How to import completed FF7 Rebirth save data to skip flashback sequence?
I successfully imported the save data the first time from multiple things (FF7 Remake, FF7 rebirth demo, etc), but then after the first cutscene leading to Zack, seeing I couldn't save when pausing, turned the power off my playstation 5 from the menu to go do something else.
Now no save data gets recognized, I tried redownloading the demo and recompleting the last cutscene from my save where Cloud crawls in the fiery town to Sephiroth doing his business to the town.
Has anybody had any success in getting save data import to work?

Have you tried deleting FF7 Rebirth save data? Or even uninstalling it?

I was expecting to get to skip the entire section but apparently you have to redo

the first fight as Sephiroth,
then progress to the credits after walking around town
when you walk up the mountain for a while you get a prompt to skip
then wake up to go find Sephiroth then redo the slow QTE crawl sequence

You get to skip the middle combat and puzzle sections on the mountain. You still need to manually skip cutscenes you've already seen.
